# Difference between @select with if and nested <xsl:choice>?

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath, xslt-2.0, xpath-2.0

Is there a reason why the following two pieces variable definitions should behave differently?

The first definition uses XPath 2 an `if` statement:

```
<xsl:variable name="content" select="if ($next-divm)
    then (./following-sibling::node() intersect $next-divm/preceding-sibling::node())
    else (./following-sibling::node())"/>
```

The second definition uses `<xsl:choose>` to reach the same result (or so I'd think):

```
<xsl:variable name="content1">
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$next-divm">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./following-sibling::node() intersect $next-divm/preceding-sibling::node()"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="./following-sibling::node()"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:variable>
```

However, these two techniques lead to two different results when `$content` is output using

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$content" mode="keep"/>
```

In the first case all the content is correctly copied (i.e all the elements and text nodes are preserved), while in the latter only the text nodes are preserved. This strange behaviour may be linked to the following other two templates.

```
<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::divm)][./preceding-sibling::divm]"/>

<xsl:template match="node()[not(self::divm)][./preceding-sibling::divm]" mode="keep">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" mode="keep"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Regardless of my specific templates, I would like to know why the two `<xsl:variable>` styles can lead to different results.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The XPath `if` is returning the original nodes from the input, still attached to their original contexts in the input tree.  The `choose` version is returning *new* nodes that are *copies* of the input nodes, and when you navigate the `preceding-sibling::` axis from these nodes you're only looking at the temporary tree in the variable, not the nodes' original context in the source XML.

If you want to capture the original nodes rather than copies in the `xsl:choose` variant then use `xsl:sequence` instead of `xsl:copy-of`.  You will also need to make the variable typed by adding something like `as="node()*"`.  [Section 9.4 of the XSLT 2.0 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#temporary-trees) explains why (my bold):

> A document node is created implicitly when evaluating an `xsl:variable`, `xsl:param`, or `xsl:with-param` element that has non-empty content **and that has no `as` attribute**. [...] The value of the variable is a **single node**, the document node of the temporary tree. The content of the document node is formed from the result of evaluating the sequence constructor

If you *do* provide `as="node()*"` then the nodes produced by the sequence constructor (i.e. the content of the `xsl:variable` element) are used as-is rather than forming the content of a new implicit document node.

Comment: It's not just beneficial, it is *essential*, to add the "as" attribute if you want to return original nodes rather than copies.

Comment: Thanks. The combination of `xsl:sequence` and `as="node()*"` did the trick; I had already tried with `xsl:sequence` alone but that did not work.

Comment: @MichaelKay: could you please explain why is the `as` attribute necessary to return the original sequence of nodes?